# Invalid SQL Server Table Object

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have server with only two databases; in one database I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WR_Shipping](
    [ShipmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShippedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShippingMethod] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ShippingTrackingNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ShippedVIA] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [TrackingURLAppConfig] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ShipmentNotes] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I can read from the table when logged on the SQL Server Manager as an admin without issue. My web application logs on to the server with a different user ID. I've checked that that user ID has `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `EXECUTE` permission on the entire database. I've also check to make sure that the effective permissions for this table are correct for this user. I've even logged on to SSMS as the web application would and can execute `SELECT * FROM WR_Shipping` without issue. However, I can execute `SELECT * FROM Product` with no problem.

I've dropped and recreated the table several times. I have the same table running in my production database, and I can connect to it without issue using the same code.

I've tried every way I can think of naming the table: `WR_Shipping`, `wr_shipping`, `dbo.WR_Shipping`, `[database].dbo.WR_Shipping`. None of those work; all generate the same error. However, they all work just fine from the SQL Server Management Console. I can't even run something as simple as `SELECT * FROM WR_Shipping` from the web app.

The error I receive is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'WR_Shipping'.` This error is throw when I try to execute SqlCommand.ExecuteReader. That command is in a routine that I use all over my web app. It takes in a string (the SQL) and a connection, and returns an `IDataReader`.

**Update**

I've tried everything that has been suggested here to no avail. Every query I tried works, even against other tables in the same database and schema. This one table never worked. I ended up cloning the production database and using that as my test database instead of continuing to work with this database. Previously I had just been committing the same changes to both databases (production and test).

Comment: You sql script is retrieving data from that table alone?

Comment: Correct. I can't even execute `select * from wr_shipping` without getting the error.

Comment: Just clarify, please: if you log into SSMS with the user ID that you're using in your code, are you able to SELECT from the table?

Comment: how many databases you have under same server? Yes you are using sale login info as in your connection string when you login SSMS, there should not be problem.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo There are two databases on the server.

Comment: I cannot see any issue if you confirmed that you are  using same login detail as in your connection string and SSMS login.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo, neither can I, which is why I'm posting here:)

Comment: Try select GETDATE().  Try using the 3 part name in the select statement.

Comment: In SSMS try Object Explorer Details.  I once had a messed up table that did not show up in regular Explorer that I was able to delete from Details.

Comment: @Blam, that statement didn't work. I've also tried dropping and recreating the table several times.

Comment: Does select GETDATE() work?  Can you create a table of a different name and have it work?  Sometimes the schema just get messed up.  Did you stop and start SQL?

Answer (score 0):

First, verify the connection string stored in the application's config file is correct.

Assuming all looks good, try these two items:

In your code, set a breakpoint before your command's ExecuteReader (or similar).  When you hit the breakpoint, drill into the Command's Connection property, and check the connection string being used.  Make sure the connection string is the one you were expecting.

If that doesn't identify the issue, and if you have permissions to use SQL Profiler, set up a session to capture the traffic hitting the database with the application's userid.  When you try your code, see what the actual SQL command is that is being sent, and debug from there.

Comment: I can see the SQL that is being executed by the command, so unless it changes internally in some .Net libraries, I know what it hitting the database. There is only one connection string, and other calls to the DB are working fine. And SQL Server Express doesn't have SQL Profiler (that I know of). (Sorry I didn't mention that at the outset.)

Comment: Also, since the same code runs fine when I change my connection string to point to the production server, it must be database related.